# how to add custom block same as related product block in product page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am using magento 2.3. We need custom block same as related products and also custom block under related products in product page. Please reply as soon as possible. Thank you

Comment: how you will assign product to that custom block ?

Comment: we need consumables and spares product for our main product. So, we decide to link related product and consumables also. But magento had related product. But we need consumables product also , so only we need to create custom block . I dnt know how to create ?.

Comment: To add same type of related products you can use upsell product features so assign upsell products same as related and they will show on product page as separate section and then rename them as consumables product